# Grid with default filter causes error Z[(l || "eq").toLowerCase(...)] is not a function

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to filter the grid directly when calling. I have set here with:

```
filter: {
  field: "Discontinued"       
  operator: "isFalse"       
  value: "true"     
},
```

Unfortunately, then an error message appears:

> Uncaught TypeError: Z [(l || "eq"). ToLowerCase (...)] is not a function

Here is my [demo grid](https://dojo.telerik.com/@blockbaster/UjAcORiB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have confused the *isTrue* message property with an operator. `isTrue` is not a valid operator according to this [doc](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter#filter.operator). I have changed the `isTrue` to `eq` and it works. I think that if you want to check the property `Discontinued` for `true`, you need to set the filter `value` property to `true`(as you did already) and the `operator` to `eq`. [Check this](https://dojo.telerik.com/edaBAfaL).